# Windows Security - Actions Recommended

Tags: security, windows-11

My Windows Security icon is flagged, and I'm trying to remove it:

[image: Flagged Windows Defender]

When I review, it says the problem is with "App & browser control":

[image: App and Browser Control]

Next, the flag is on "Reputation-based protection", with a "Potentially unwated app found":

[image: Reputation Based Protection]

Finally, I click "Review" and and it says "No Recent Actions".

So what is it complaining about?

Even the "Dismiss" button here does absolutely nothing:

[image: Dismiss Button]

[image: Protection History]

Comment: Are you looking to just clear the status? The item quarantined or that was flagged for review has likely already been deleted hence the reason the list is empty.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes just to clear the status.  There is a "dismiss" button directly under "App and Browser Control", but clicking on this does nothing.   I'd like a clean taskbar without this flag drawing my attention to a potential issue, when there are no potential issues.